# woo commerce - add variable text to product variations

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have some product variations set in woo commerce, and i need to add some text somewhere, describing which variation is shown in the product image.

We are dealing with number of flowers, so the variations are 10 stems, 20 stems, 30 stems etc... but I need to be able to say the image for that particular product shows 30 stems... the complicated thing is the number of stems in the image varies for each product - So yellow roses might be 10 stems in the image and red roses might be 40 stems..

If i put the text next to the particular variation, it might ruin the responsiveness, so perhaps i need a line of text underneath the options??

I have attached a pic of what it looks like now.. I also need to add prices to each variation but that's a problem for another day!

If anyone has any ideas of how to do this i'd greatly appreciate them. Thanks.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: There is a description text field for each variation, and also a price is displayed for each variation, so you don't need any additional code.

Comment: Do you mean in the products > attributes menu? The description doesn't seem to show by default for my theme... also, wouldn't this set the description at a global level? I need to be able to customise it per product? I don't see a price display field??

Comment: Ahh I see. Is there a way to make this text always show? It seems to only display when that option is selected. I want to make it very clear to customers what option the image is, that they're looking at...

Comment: Yes that works on selected variations (same thing for the prices). You can pre-select a variation by default, so a text and a price will always be displayed when the product loads. So this is just about settings and about slyling (CSS).

Comment: okay great.. thank works! Thanks! Is there a way to get the description inline with the option?? Also, I don't see how to get the price to display though? I want it to be inline with the options.. and also be responsive when viewing on a mobile device? Thanks

Comment: Normally by default on Woocommerce, every variation data (price, availability, description and image) is displayed dynamically for the selected variation. So if is not the case, the problem comes from your theme or a plugin.

Comment: Yes, sorry it is displayed dynamically... but i want the variations to always show the price next to it.. so customers don't have to select options to see what the prices are..

Comment: That is an advanced customization that is simply too broad for StackOverFlow as you don't provide any code in your answer. Also your screenshot shows already some customizations that doesn't exist by default on Woocommerce and nobody can guess how this has been done. Please remember that StackOverFlow is not a free coding service.

Comment: okay.. i don't know where the code comes from.. so i don't know what to share exactly.. but thanks anyway :)